# calculating $1024\times(1.11111111)_{2}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binary, floating-point

### Question

calculate $1024\times(1.11111111)_{2}$  in terms of power of $10$

### My Confusion/Approach

> $1024*(1.11111111)_{2}=2^{10}(2-2^{-8})=2^{11}-2^{2}=2^{2}(2^{9}-1)$

I am not getting how $(1.11111111)_{2}=(2-2^{-8})$

I know its basic but can't figure out.
Please help me out !

Comment: Write out $2$ and $2^{-8}$ in binary, and it might be clearer why you get what you get when you subtract them.

Comment: $00000010-(0.00000001)$

Comment: Remember, multiplying by power of $2$ is equivalent to shifting the bits to the left and inserting $0$'s ! For example $2.25_{10} = 10.01_2$, then say we multiply by $4=2^2$, we then get $9_{10} = 1001_2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}1.11111111_2&=2^0+2^{-1}+2^{-2}+2^{-3}+2^{-4}+2^{-5}+2^{-6}+2^{-7}+2^{-8}\\&=2^{-8}(1+2+2^2+2^3+2^4+2^5+2^6+2^7+2^8)\\&=2^{-8}\frac{2^9-1}{2-1}\\&=2-2^{-8}.\end{align}

Comment: that is what i was expecting :) thanks

Comment: @laura I'm glad I could help. However, for me, the way of doing this is the one suggested by Arthur at the comments. I only posted my answer because you did not seem interested in his approach.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $$(0.11111111)_2=\left(\frac 12+\frac 1{2^2}+\ldots+\frac 1{2^8}\right)_{10}$$

Answer (score 0):

$(1.11111111)_2=(2−2^{−8})$

$(1.11111111)_2=10_2 -0.00000001_2=2-2^{-8}$

like 999=1000-1 simply